# Angular 6 - Reusable component - Route navigation

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently, am rendering exactly the same table structure which is in a shared folder,  for three different components. The issue, I'm having back button on the table, whenever I click on that it should navigate back to the component view from its actually came from.

**Assumption:**

```
componentA -> commonTblCompoent - click Back - go to componentA 
componentB -> commonTblCompoent - click Back - go to componentB 
componentC -> commonTblCompoent - click Back - go to componentC
```

Right now navigation is only happening to componentA. How to change route config smartly.

**compoentA.ts**

```
gotoCommonTbl {
    this.router.navigate(['cmnTable/commonTbl']);
}
```

**compoentB.ts**

```
gotoCommonTbl {
    this.router.navigate(['cmnTable/commonTbl']);
}
```

**commonTbl.ts**

```
gotocurrentComponent() {
//this.router.navigate(['componentA/comp-A']);

// this is supposed to be changed for proper navigation
}
```

Could someone tell me how to rewrite and fix this issue? if possible, kindly share any sample working demo

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the `Location` class in `CommonTbl` and sending the user back where they came from:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }

gotocurrentComponent() {
  this.location.back();
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yajvoj